# Spark application that save file as .txt.gz in SFTP

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sftp

I have `Spark`(Scala) application that save specific dataframe in `SFTP` as **.txt** file. The file that the application generated some times reached 20GB; which is something that can't be downloaded by consumers. I am thinking that I can zip the file such that we reduce the size of the file ( specially it is a text file that we expect a good compression ratio).

Is there any reference or library that I need to work with (import) in `Spark` that can give me a compressed file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

You can compress a file using `option("codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappyCodec")`. There are many codecs available which offers different level of compression like `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec`.

This won't have any effect if the file is saved as .txt , but works amazingly if you use `csv`,`parquet` or `Avro` format. Both parquet and Avro format are splittable in compressed state so you needn't uncompress manually before processing, spark will automatically uncompress.

Code to read text and save as parquet -

```
val df = spark.read.text("path to text file")

df.write.option("codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappyCodec").parquet("destination path")

//read the file back
spark.read.parquet("path to compressed file").show()
```

Code to read CSV and save as csv.gz.

```
val df = spark.read.csv("path to test.csv")
df.write.option("codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec").csv("path to test2.gzip")
```

Answer (score 0):

So I went through different approaches trying to have the `.txt.gz` file saved in the `SFTP`. Some Googling I found [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/fileinputstream/compress-a-file-in-gzip-format-in-java/) which is a `Java` code that compress a text file into `.gz`, I just rewrite this code in `Scala` and everything went perfect.

```
def zipFile(fileName1: String): Int = {
val gzpFile: String =  fileNameDotTxt + ".gz"

val SOURCE_FILE: String = pathToFileNameDotTxt 
val buffer: Array[Byte] = Array.ofDim[Byte](1024)
try {
  val gzos: GZIPOutputStream = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(gzpFile))
  val in: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(SOURCE_FILE)
  var len: Int = 0
  while ({ len = in.read(buffer); len } > 0) gzos.write(buffer, 0, len)
  in.close()
  gzos.finish()
  gzos.close()


} catch {
  case ex: IOException =>
    ex.printStackTrace()

}
```

}

We need to import

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream
```

Hope this will makes some helps for others.